# How can i share ubuntu's internet to iphone via USB

Tags: usb, unix, tethering

Can anyone help me reverse tethering from linux to iphone 5.

Comment: Like @Matteo said this is not something you do on the iPhone, it is something you do on your Ubuntu PC. you may want to ask this question on https://askubuntu.com or ask for this question to be migrated there...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if iPhone 5 has this feature, but it does exist at least since iPhone 8.

To reverse tether Ubuntu internet connection to your iPhone, build and install [usbmuxd](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/usbmuxd) from sources (the latest release does not include my [PR](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/usbmuxd/pull/206)).

Set environment variable `USBMUXD_DEFAULT_DEVICE_MODE`=`3` for the installed service.

Then, connect your device to the Linux machine, and it should immediately create a new NIC on your machine.

In the network settings of Ubuntu, you should now be able to "Share Internet Connection" (which will add a couple of `iptables` rules behind the scenes) and use the connection on your iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from @Elist is exactly what i needed. I don't have reputation for comment his answer, upvoted it.
As for today [usbmuxd](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/usbmuxd) included that patch.
To set environment variable for usbmuxd service - one can create systemd override conf by

> sudo systemctl edit usbmuxd.service

and add there

> [Service]
> Environment=USBMUXD_DEFAULT_DEVICE_MODE=3

Answer (score -1):

You cannot configure a network connection using USB on the iPhone. If your Ubuntu machine has a wireless adapter you will have to configure it as an access point.